# How to detect and connect to two active devices within the range using Google Nearby Connections API?

Tags: android, google-nearby

I'm trying to create an app,which discovers devices around it and transfer's messages automatically.I'm using Google Nearby Connections API.

The problem I'm facing is that when two devices are active,then the new device detects only one of those two active device.

Is there any way,all the devices within the range can be detected?Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Calling 'startDiscovery' should see every other phone that has called 'startAdvertising'.

For connecting, 'Strategy.P2P_CLUSTER' will let you connect to a variety of devices at once. 'Strategy.P2P_STAR' will let you have 1 outgoing connection or multiple incoming connections.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for the late reply. I was working with WiFi P2P service discovery and I feel it is so unreliable after working on it for a month. Moving back again to Google Nearby!

Comment: Just use `Strategy.P2P_CLUSTER`.This will suffice your requirement. But you need to have a compatible app (packed with nearby) as a discoverer installed in those devices which you want to be discovered from your app. Hope this helps!